# How to receive UDP traffic from multicast adress with Python on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: networking, python

I have an ethernet device sending UDP packets to multicast address 224.0.2.2 on port 42102. I'm able to capture packets from wireshark or tcpdump, but when I try to open a socket and bind it to multicast port I never receive anything. I believe this has something to do with my Ubuntu setup because I can get packets with the same python script on Windows but not Ubuntu 22.04.

For the basic code, I've tried many variations of the following. I've tried running as sudo, etc with no luck. The ip address of the connected interface (enp12s0) is 10.13.1.100.

```
import socket
import struct

def mc_recv(fromnicip, mcgrpip, mcport):
    # This creates a UDP socket
    sock = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM, \
            proto=socket.IPPROTO_UDP, fileno=None)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    bindaddr = (mcgrpip, mcport)
    sock.bind(bindaddr)

    mreq = struct.pack("=4s4s", socket.inet_aton(mcgrpip), socket.inet_aton(fromnicip))
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

    while True:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        print(f"Received packet from {addr}: {data.decode('utf-8')}")

def main():

    fromnicip = '10.13.1.100'
    mcgrpip = '224.0.2.2'
    mcport = 42102

    mc_recv(fromnicip, mcgrpip, mcport)
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

So far, I haven't received any UDP packets in any configuration.

For reference, if I run tshark with

```
sudo tshark -f "host 224.0.2.2" -f "port 42102" -i enp12s0
```

the captured packet summaries look like

```
   59 0.949480840  10.13.1.113 → 224.0.2.2    UDP 130 42402 → 42102 Len=84
   60 1.000030440  10.13.1.113 → 224.0.2.2    UDP 130 42402 → 42102 Len=84
```

As I said above, I tried the code above on a windows boot on the same machine and it works. I guess it has something to do with the network configuration on the linux side, but I'm at a loss as to what the issue may be. Noting that firewall issues were the solution in some similar questions about this issue I tried

```
sudo ufw status
```

and it returned

```
Status: inactive
```

Is there something else that could explain what's going on with the disparity between the Python results on Windows and Ubuntu?

Comment: Does Python support error checking? As a non-python, network programmer, your assumption that "everything works" seems unwise.

Comment: Totally fair that the assumption that the code works in itself is something to push on. It does support some error checking that is relevant for this. For example, the sock.bind() line can generate a return value. I have captured that and it indicates nominal operation. Also, after binding the port I've used netstat to check and it looks to me like the port is bound correctly. Also, the same code (and a few other variations I've tried) do end up capturing packets with as close to the same configuration as I can get under windows.

Is there some aspect in particular you had in mind to check?